# Hadoop server run wizard is not opening in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, cygwin

I have configured the Hadoop installation directory location(C:\cygwin\home\hadoop-0.19.1) but whenever i am running the .java file as run on Hadoop it is not displaying Hadoop server run wizard and it's not running.Please help me to come out of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Eclipse Indego 3.7 version which was not working previously so i degraded the Eclipse version to 3.3. As i googled i came to know that there are some changes happened for Hadoop plugin in Eclipse latest versions which are released after 3.3